# Perform ifelse() on every element of a data frame, but different test for each column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I've got a large data frame [4000,600] and I'd like to convert elements to 0 if they are smaller than three orders of magnitude less than each column maximum.  So each element would need to be compared to the maximum value of its column and if the element < 0.001*$column_max then it should be converted to 0 and if it isn't, it should remain the same.

I am having a tough time getting apply() to let me use an ifelse() function.  Is there a better approach or function I am missing??  I'm fairly new to R.

Comment: I would suggest posting a segment of your code if you want a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `lapply` to loop over each column with a `replace` call:

```
dat <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,1001),b=c(3,4,3003))
dat
#     a    b
#1    1    3
#2    2    4
#3 1001 3003

dat[] <- lapply(dat, function(x) replace(x, x < max(x)/10^3, 0) )
dat
#     a    b
#1    0    0
#2    2    4
#3 1001 3003
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work with ifelse if you use apply column-wise:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1:10, 4000), b = c(4:13, 7000))

apply(df, 2, function(x){ifelse(x < 0.001*max(x), 0, x)})
```

Answer (score 1):

We could do this without using `ifelse`

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
    mutate_each(funs((.>= 0.001*max(.))*.))
#     a    b
#1    0    0
#2    2    4
#3 1001 3003
```

#### data

```
dat <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,1001),b=c(3,4,3003))
```